# Правильная ссылка или нет?

Tags: javascript, dom

Правильно ли я сделал ссылку?
Или коряво? И можно оптимизировать?

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].innerHTML;
document.write("<a href='https://yandex.ru/maps/11307/kansk/?text=" + x + "' target='_blank' title='Показать " + x + " на карте'><h4>" + x + "</h4></a>");

var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[1].innerHTML;
document.write("<a href='https://yandex.ru/maps/11307/kansk/?text=" + x + "' target='_blank' title='Показать " + x + " на карте'><h4>" + x + "</h4></a>");
```

```html
<h4 style="display:none;">Центральная Городская библиотека им. Чехова</h4>

<h4 style="display:none;">Кинотеатр "Космос"</h4>
```

Comment: если работает значит правильно)

Comment: a почему display:none  ?)

Comment: @FəqanÇələbizadə, так иначе дублируется название.

Comment: а вообще этот заголовок нужен?

Comment: @Grundy пока не знаю. Я скопировал голый HTML и теперь АСУчиваю его так сказать. Можно конечно и DIV'ом заменить с class'ом. Но пока так. Пока только develop-version.
А список большой. 200-300 организаций.

Answer (score 1):

Стиль `display: none` можно заменить на [`hidden`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/embed/hidden).
Сохраняйте имена для поиска в массив, а не скрытые элементы, ибо доступ к `DOM` всегда очень дорогой. Т. е. на двух элементах это не очень скажется, конечно, но всё же оптимизация.

```js
let tags = [
  `Центральная Городская библиотека им. Чехова`,
  `Кинотеатр "Космос"`
];

tags.forEach(x => 
  document.write(`<a href='https://yandex.ru/maps/11307/kansk/?text=${encodeURIComponent(x)}' target='_blank' title='Показать ${x} на карте'><h4>${x}</h4></a>`));
```

**UPDATE:**

Для FF v42, Chrome v46, Safаri v5.1.7:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var tags = [
    'Центральная Городская библиотека им. Чехова',
    'Кинотеатр "Космос"'
  ];

  tags.forEach(function(x) {
    document.write("<a href='https://yandex.ru/maps/11307/kansk/?text=" + encodeURIComponent(x) + "' target='_blank' title='Показать " + x + " на карте'><h4>" + x + "</h4></a>");
  });
}());
```

Comment: стоит добавить, что используемые `Template Strings` пока не работают в IE

Comment: @Grundy, так же можно отметить что `IE` - вообще на редкость большой камень на шее прогресса и поддерживать б-гомерзкие старые версии не нужно ИМХО. Не указано насколько кроссбраузерно это должно работать, в `IE` вполне могут глупить и новые записи функций.

Comment: @Other в FF v42 Ваш скрипт не работает. Chromium v46 - не работает.
И если брать скорость, то даже эти 2 пункта выводятся по скорости в 2 раза медленнее, чем мой аналог.

Comment: @Other Safаry 5.1.7 - не работает

Comment: @I_CaR, используются новинки ES6. FF42 не терпит `let`. Chrome46 - не поддерживает работу с новинками без строгого режима. Safari вообще многого не реализовала. Скорость в них, сами понимаете, будет меньше - старые версии НЕ оптимизированы к новому. Обновлю ответ для них, новый пример там работать будет.

Comment: @Other Вот смотрите, в моём примере (jsfiddle - не срабатывает его корректно), просто посмотрите код: https://jsfiddle.net/1zttjnua/
Так вот в моем примере, после `<H4>` идёт ещё и доп.информация, аля телефон и сайт и т.п. Вот как в вашем варианте это всё происходит? Немного не понимаю.

Comment: В вопросе ничего про телефоны не сказано. Их тоже можно добавлять динамически, раз вообще встал вопрос о добавлении чего-то. Ведь если код генерируется сервером, просто проставьте там ссылки, если это подгружается (аля AJAX) - телефоны тоже будут только в ответе, но не разметке, смекаешь?